# How can I include HTML and JavaScript code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design, stack-snippets

I want to post my first question here, and I would like to insert HTML and JavaScript code.

I've been checking questions to different answers, and there is a "run code" button that runs both HTML and JavaScript.

I also see in some answers that they use a "code snippet button" that used to be next to the "images" button, but I cannot see it anymore.

How should I post my HTML and JavaScript code for other users to see what is happening?

Sorry if this is the most basic of the questions, but I do not find a recent answer and I am not sure how to use the code block linking both languages.

Comment: Oh, it looks like we have a bug (MSE): [Code Snippet tool is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381279/code-snippet-tool-is-missing)

Comment: The stack-snippet editor option is gone when asking a new question. Once you posted the question the stack-snippet editor option does show-up in the toolbar

Comment: thanks @rene , is that a bug that will be fixed, or is it a permanent thing?

Comment: I assume it is a regression that is introduced with one of the last deploys. I expect it to be restored soon™

Comment: The bug is now status-review which means that SE staff is aware of the problem.

Comment: [Now fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381284)!